# Pass parameter\variable from .vbs to .bat

Tags: variables, batch-file, vbscript, parameters

I'm trying to pass a variable from a VBS to BAT but i'm getting "The system cannot find the file specified"

Here is my vbs :

```
 Option Explicit

Dim strFile

strFile = SelectFile( )

If strFile = "" Then 
    WScript.Echo "No file selected."
Else
    WScript.Echo """" & strFile & """"
End If


Function SelectFile( )

    Dim objExec, strMSHTA, wshShell

    SelectFile = ""


    strMSHTA = "mshta.exe ""about:" & "<" & "input type=file id=FILE>" _
             & "<" & "script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')" _
             & ".GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);" & "<" & "/script>"""

    Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
    Set objExec = wshShell.Exec( strMSHTA )

    SelectFile = objExec.StdOut.ReadLine( )


Dim wshShelll
Set WshShelll = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShelll.Run "C:\Users\nbendjelida\Desktop\email.bat" & SelectFile


    Set objExec = Nothing
    Set wshShell = Nothing
    Set wshShelll = Nothing
End Function
```

here is my bat :

```
 "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\Outlook.exe" /eml %1
```

do you have any idea ?

Comment: Try with a space at the end of `WshShelll.Run "C:\Users\nbendjelida\Desktop\email.bat "`

Comment: amazing, that worked :) i've been stuck for 2 days !! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I repeat the right answer of [sachadee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2414894/sachadee) with more details to get this question removed from the list of unanswered questions.

[Run Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx) must be called with first parameter being the command to execute with the parameters exactly as when entering the command in the command line window. The examples on the referenced Microsoft help page have also a space character after the command `Notepad`.

The command line required to call the batch file with a file name as first parameter is:

```
C:\Users\nbendjelida\Desktop\email.bat name_of_selected_file
```

But the Windows script host code line

```
WshShelll.Run "C:\Users\nbendjelida\Desktop\email.bat" & SelectFile
```

builds the string for the command to run as

```
C:\Users\nbendjelida\Desktop\email.bat name_of_selected_file
```

because of the missing space character.

The problem is solved with the correct Windows script host code line

```
WshShelll.Run "C:\Users\nbendjelida\Desktop\email.bat " & SelectFile
```

because of the space charater between name of batch file and name of selected file.

---

If name of selected file contains 1 or more spaces, it is necessary that either variable `SelectFile` contains already a double quote at beginning and at end, or the necessary double quotes are added on concatenating the command string.

Example with entire batch file name also containing a space character:

```
Dim FileName
FileName = "%TEMP%\Any File.txt"
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run """%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\My Batch File.bat"" """ & FileName & """"
```

The batch file `My Batch File.bat` on desktop of current user containing

```
@echo %0 %*
@pause
```

outputs for example on Windows 7

```
"C:\Users\username\Desktop\My Batch File.bat" "C:\User\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Any File.txt"
```

or on English Windows XP

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\user name\Desktop\My Batch File.bat" "C:\Documents and Settings\user name\Local Settings\Temp\Any File.txt"
```

which are the expected results for the command string.

(Yes, a user name can contain a space character although Microsoft recommends not to use a space character in user name, see Microsoft page [Creating User and Group Accounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726984.aspx).)